# Reload/Refresh View Controller with a specific subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i have a UIViewController with several specific subviews (like PassBook Views). 
When i exit a view i want to reload the ViewController and all his subviews. i call the viewDidLoad and viewWillLayoutSubviews method of the rootviewController like this:

```
- (IBAction)disconnect:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    self.sourceVC = segue.sourceViewController;
    self.disconnected = YES;
    ViewController *rootController=(ViewController *)((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController;
    [rootController viewDidLoad];
    [rootController viewWillLayoutSubviews];}
```

in my ViewController class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self setupPBDataSource];}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
CGFloat maxY = (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)\
                ? 20 : 0);
frame.origin.y += maxY;
frame.size.height -= maxY;

if (!_passbookView) {
    self.passbookView =
    [[PBPassGroupStackView alloc] initWithFrame:frame datasource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.passbookView];
} else {
    [self.passbookView removeFromSuperview];
    self.passbookView =
    [[PBPassGroupStackView alloc] initWithFrame:frame datasource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:_passbookView];
}}
```

i just want to know how to reload my new passbookView (with two new subviews created on a login segue) ??? thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` directly. You could create new methods that encapsulate roughly what you're attempting, but calling them directly is unconventional.

Comment: And what the way to reload all the views in my passbookView instead off removeFromSuperview and addSubview ?

Comment: I don't know anything about `PBPassGroupStackView`. Is there a `reloadData`? You should look up the API.